# How print two different select results

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/file.pf')

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select something from table1') #1st select
cur.execute('select something_else from table2') #2nd select
rows = cur.fetchall()

for r in rows:
    print r
```

I only get the results from the first `SELECT`.

How can I include the rows from the second `SELECT` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two separate cursors, or create a `UNION` select to produce *one* result.

Two separate cursors can be chained together with [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

cur1 = con.cursor()
cur1.execute('select something from table1') #1st select
cur2 = con.cursor()
cur2.execute('select something_else from table2') #2nd select

for row in chain(cur1, cur2):
    print row
```

Note that you don't have to call `cursor.fetchall()`; iteration can be done over the rows directly.

A `UNION` select requires that your selects return the same number of columns:

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execut('''\
    select something from table1  -- 1st select
    union
    select something_else from table2  -- 2nd select
''')

for row in cur:
    print row
```